# How to make a <div> display its own width as text inside it?

Tags: java, html, width

thanks for reading.

I have a forum and I'm trying to add a java applet into it that is the same width as the post it's contained in. Therefore before I compile the JAR I need to know the width of the posts, which is the maximum width the applet can be.

What I need to know is how to make a div that is width 100%, so it stretches to the very sides of the post and inside the div it tells me how wide it is. It would be extremely helpful as I can't measure with a program how wide the post is because I can't see the boundaries due to the design.

Thanks in advance so much for helping,
Gergy.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (assuming you're using jQuery!):

```
$(".my_div").html($(".my_div").width());
```

Without jQuery, give this a shot:

```
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>

    <div id="mydiv">

    </div>

    <script>
       var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
       div.innerHTML = (div.offsetWidth);
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was looking more basic than that, for example basic javascript, I would use jQuery if my forum supported it :(

Thanks for replying!

Comment: I'll work on converting this down to standard JS, hang tight :)

Comment: @Gergy I updated my answer with a standard JS implementation - see if that works for you - Also, just curious, what forum software are you running? I know a lot of the out-of-the-box type solutions for CMS's and whatnot have the ability to include custom scripts

Comment: @Evan this is a good answer but why does MDN say "offsetWidth is a property of the DHTML object model which was first introduced by MSIE. It is sometimes referred to as an element's physical/graphical dimensions, or an element's border-box width."? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth) Do you know any official way? `div.style.width` doesn't work on Chrome.

Comment: Hey Ray - getting the width with standard JS, from my research, appears to be very browser specific (hence preference towards jQuery here) - I use Chrome myself, and the solution I found was offset width - I'll check to see if there is a more appropriate approach, this seemed to be fine from the little sample I worked up to test it, but admittedly I didn't try it everywhere!